# explicit specialization of template class member function

Tags: c++, class, templates, function, specifications

I have this :

```
template<class T, class U>
class A
{
    template<size_t N>
    void BindValues();
}

template<class T, class U>
template<size_t N>
inline void A<T, U>::BindValues()
{
    conn->setValue<N-1>( std::get<N-1>(m_Tuple) );
    BindValues<N-1>(conn);
}

template<class T, class U>
template<>
inline void A<T, U>::BindValues<1>()
{
    conn->setValue<0>( std::get<0>(m_Tuple) );
}
```

My Compile error is:

```
invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
template-id BindValues<1> for void A<T, U>::BindValues() does not match any template declaration
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately a `template` method inside a `template` class cannot be specialized just based on `template` argument of method.

You **need to specialize the `template class` also**. In other words, the member method specialization should be a **complete specialization** with respect to `class template` (i.e. `<T,U>`) params as well as the member `template` params (i.e. `<size_t>`).

For example, you may have to specialize something like this ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/11rJB)):

```
template<>  // <------ you have to specialize class also
template<>
inline void A<int, double>::BindValues<1>()  // <-------- see A<T,U>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @russellsayshi, even I don't have any logical explanation for it. One possibility is to reduce the complexity of the C++ grammar parser, since this feature may not be used so often.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is partial template specialization for a function, which is not allowed.

You can define the template function on `N` for a template specialization of A (e.g. `A<int, int>::BindValues<N>()`) but the other way around is not allowed.