# c++ template class member function specialization

Tags: c++, function, templates, specialization

I have a problem where I want to specialize a template member function of a template class in the code below. The answer to  this question [explicit specialization of template class member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546629/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function) seems to suggest that it can't be done. Is that correct, and if so, is there any work around I can use so that by inline inc functions get expanded at compile time?

Many thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template <class IT, unsigned int N>
struct IdxIterator {
private:
  int startIdx[N], endIdx[N];  
  int curIdx[N];
  IT iter;

public:
  IdxIterator(IT it, int cur[], int start[], int end[]): iter(it) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      curIdx[i] = cur[i];
      startIdx[i] = start[i];
      endIdx[i] = end[i];
    }
  }

  template <int dim>
  inline void inc() {
    curIdx[dim]++;
    if (curIdx[dim] > endIdx[dim]) {
      if (dim > 0) {
        curIdx[dim] = startIdx[dim];
        inc<dim-1>();
      }
    }
  }

  // how to declare this specialization?
  template <> template <>
  inline void inc<-1>() {
    std::cerr << "IdxIterator::inc(" << -1 << ") dim out of bounds!\n";
    throw 1;
  }

  inline IdxIterator<IT, N> operator++() {
    iter++;
    inc<N-1>();
    return *this;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int *buf = new int[100];
  int start[1], end[1];
  start[0] = 0; end[0] = 99;
  IdxIterator<int*, 1> it(buf, start, start, end);
  ++it;

  return 0;

}
```

G++ spits out:

> test2.cpp:32:13: error: explicit specialisation in non-namespace scope
>   ‘struct IdxIterator’ test2.cpp:32:25: error: explicit
>   specialisation in non-namespace scope ‘struct IdxIterator’
>   test2.cpp:33:23: error: template-id ‘inc<-0x00000000000000001>’ in
>   declaration of primary template test2.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   IdxIterator::inc() [with int dim = -0x000000000000003fe, IT =
>   int*, unsigned int N = 1u]’: test2.cpp:27:9: error: template
>   instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 1024 (use -ftemplate-depth= to
>   increase the maximum) instantiating ‘void IdxIterator::inc()
>   [with int dim = -0x000000000000003ff, IT = int*, unsigned int N = 1u]’
>   test2.cpp:27:9:   recursively instantiated from ‘void IdxIterator::inc() [with int dim = -0x00000000000000001, IT = int*, unsigned
>   int N = 1u]’ test2.cpp:27:9:   instantiated from ‘void IdxIterator::inc() [with int dim = 0, IT = int*, unsigned int N = 1u]’
>   test2.cpp:41:5:   instantiated from ‘IdxIterator
>   IdxIterator::operator++() [with IT = int*, unsigned int N =
>   1u]’ test2.cpp:53:5:   instantiated from here
>
> test2.cpp: At global scope: test2.cpp:22:15: warning: inline function
>   ‘void IdxIterator::inc() [with int dim = -0x000000000000003ff,
>   IT = int*, unsigned int N = 1u]’ used but never defined [enabled by
>   default]

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, you can use a `static_assert`. Else, you could invoke instantiation of a second template (independent of `IdxIterator`) inside `inc` that does this check.

Comment: Just try to minimize the code you put into your questions!!! Most of the stuff here is not relevant to the problem at all.

Comment: This seems pretty trivial if your only issue is ensuring a positive value. 

`template<unsigned var> 
void foo() { /*impl*/ }`

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way in C++11, but you can always go via overloading instead of specialization:

```
template <int N>
struct num { };

class A
{
    template <int N>
    void f(num <N>) { };

    void f(num <-1>) { };

public:
    template <int N>
    void f() { f(num <N>()); };
};
```

Comment: This answer would need a specialization for `template<> num<0> {}` otherwise the compiler will not know when to terminate when calling `num<n-1>.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do what the compiler error message suggests:

```
template <class IT, unsigned int N>
struct IdxIterator {
private:
  template <int dim>
  inline void inc() {
    curIdx[dim]++;
    if (curIdx[dim] > endIdx[dim]) {
      if (dim > 0) {
        curIdx[dim] = startIdx[dim];
        inc<dim-1>();
      }
    }
  }
};

template <> template <>
inline void IdxIterator::inc<-1>() {
  std::cerr << "IdxIterator::inc(" << -1 << ") dim out of bounds!\n";
  throw 1;
}
```

ie move the definition to namespace-scope.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper struct outside of class

```
template<dim>
struct inc {
template<class cur, end>
      inline static void foo(cur curIdx, end endIdx) {
        curIdx[dim]++;
    if (curIdx[dim] > endIdx[dim]) {
        inc<dim-1>::foo(curIdx, endIdx);
      }
    }    
};

template<>
struct inc<0> {
    template<class cur, end>
      inline static void foo(cur, end) {
       //terminate
    }    
};

class IdxIterator {
       template<int i>
       void inc() {
        static_assert(i > 0, "error out of bounds");
         int<i>::foo(/*params*/); 
    }

};
```

Note if you are using the GCC you may `__attribute__((always_inline))`to force inlining.